# What can I use for jq < 1.6 where rawfile support is missing?

Tags: json, jq

In jq, `--rawfile <variable-name> <filename>` will read in the named file and bind its content to the given global variable. If you run jq with `--rawfile foo bar`, then `$foo` is  available in the program and has a string whose contents are to the texts in the file named `bar`

But in versions of jq before 1.6, `--rawfile` is not present, what can I do?

The file contents are too large and/or private to pass on the command line with `--arg foo "$(cat bar)"`, `--argfile` and `--slurpfile` will expect JSON input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use bash command substitution to have jq first convert the file contents to a *single* json string which can be read with `--argfile`

`--argfile` is like `--slurpfile`, but when the file has just one text, then that is used, else an array of texts is used as in `--slurpfile`.

We are going to make sure there is *just one text* so we can ignore the warning in the man page *Do not use. Use --slurpfile instead*

So we convert from:

```
jq ... --rawfile foo ./bar
```

to

```
jq ... --argfile foo <( jq -s -R '.' ./bar )
```

`jq -s -R '.'` reads `./bar` in one go because of `-s` thus obtaining a multiline string instead of an array, and it treats the input as raw text because of `-R` and emits a single json string output.

Example:

```
$ printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\n' > 123
$ jq -n --rawfile text 123 '{ text: $text }'
{
  "text": "one\ntwo\nthree\n"
}
$ jq -n --argfile text <( jq -s -R '.' 123 ) '{ text: $text }'
{
  "text": "one\ntwo\nthree\n"
}
```

Comment: Tip: `jq -s -R '.'` can be shortened to `jq -sR .`